# NULL is appended in the beginning of the file while converting to string using toString()

Tags: java, file, tostring

```
 String message = null;    
 BufferedReader br = null;
 String s;
 br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
 String currentLine;
 while((currentLine=br.readLine()) != null)
 {
     System.out.println(currentLine);
     message+=currentLine.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.'\\s+]+","")+" ";
     System.out.println(message);
 }
```

***The file contains the data*** : Test data

***Output*** : Test data
         nullTest data

Please help me in removing the null from the first word in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I have used  String message = "" ; and I am able to get the output .

Answer (score 1):

You have null value for message variable and string concatenation doing appending null. Do the following,

```
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(); 
    BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String currentLine = null;
    while((currentLine=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
         System.out.println(currentLine);
         message.append(currentLine.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.'\\s+]+",""));
         system.out.println(message);
    }
```

Comment: As a practics, please use empty value to initialize the string objects rather than null.

Answer (score 0):

you set message null first. `String message = null;` replace with `String message = "";` this will make it an empty string and null will vanish

Answer (score 0):

Change the initial value from

```
String message = null;
```

to

```
String message = "";
```

to avoid the "null".

Or better yet, use a StringBuilder to concatenate Strings.

```
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(currentLine);
        message.append (currentLine.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.'\\s+]+",""));
        message.append (' ');
        system.out.println(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're calling `message+=` on a `null` string, so you're adding `currentLine` to null.

Simplest fix would be to set `massage` to `""` when you initialise it:

```
String message = "";
//Rest of code...
```